# Array input in single line

Tags: c#, arrays

I want to input numbers to array in a single line.
Not like this: 1
2
3

but like 1 2 3

```
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
                {
                    arr[i] = Console.Read();
                }
```

Help?

Answer (score 3):

You can read a single line and then split it like this:

```
var line = Console.ReadLine();

int[] numbers = line.Split(' ').Select(x => Convert.ToInt32(x)).ToArray();
```

Comment: Can I use this when I input numbers from keyboard, not text file?...so every time when I type number and press Enter, it goes to new line.

Comment: I am not sure I understand the rest of your comment

Answer (score 0):

This reads in each character without forcing you onto a new line or making you have to hit enter for each entry.

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
{
     arr[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadKey().KeyChar);
}
```

if you are wanting the numbers to come in as they are, instead of their ASCII index then use this instead:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
{
    arr[i] = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar - '0';
}
```